# Return top and bottom values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to return the top and bottom values in XSLT. This sorted based on `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100`. I have mentioned below the logic of how should be implemented.

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The output should be:

```
<result>
  <top>
    <tp>12<t/>+8<t/>+200</tp>
    <tp>14<t/>+5<t/>+55.55555</tp>
  </top>
  <bottom>
    <tp>3<t/>-4<t/>-57.142857</tp>
    <tp>2<t/>-7<t/>-77.7777</tp>
  </bottom>
</result>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="tp" as="element(tp)+">
        <xsl:perform-sort>
            <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="tr">
                <tp>
                    <xsl:value-of select="td[3]"/>
                    <t/>
                    <xsl:variable name="cdt" select="td[3]-td[4]"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="if ($cdt > 0) then concat('+',$cdt) else $cdt"/>
                    <t/>
                    <xsl:variable name="xat" select="(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="if ($xat > 0) then concat('+',$xat) else $xat"/>
                </tp>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <result>
        <top>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$tp[position() le 2]"/>
        </top>
        <bottom>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$tp[position() ge last() - 1]"/>
        </bottom>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

My output:

```
<result>
  <top>
    <tp>14<t/>+5<t/>+55.56</tp>
    <tp>2<t/>-7<t/>-77.78</tp>
  </top>
  <bottom>
    <tp>12<t/>+8<t/>+200.00</tp>
    <tp>3<t/>-4<t/>-57.14</tp>
  </bottom>
</result>
```

Logic:

- This one must be sorted according to `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100`
- first number must be `td[3]` ex:12,14
- second number must be `td[3] - td[4]` ex:+8,+5
- third number mut be `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100` ex:+200,+55.5555
- Conclution: I want to sort tp based on `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100` . and other values in tp `td[3]` and `td[3] - td[4]` in each sorted tp should be displayed. I mean the top tp is `+200`. it is third tr. In third `tr` `td[3]` value is `12` and `td[3]-td[4]` is `+8`

Comment: Are you asking how to sort the `tp` nodes, or how to produce the three values? Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes I want to sort `tp` based on `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100` . and other values in `tp` `td[3]` and `td[3] - td[4]` in each sorted `tp` should be displayed. I mean the top `tp` is `+200`. it is third `tr`. In third `tr` `td[3]` value is `12` and  `td[3]-td[4]` is `+8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:sort select="text()[3]" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
```

Comment: This answer is totally correct. but some `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100` I am getting `NaN` as answer. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't know. I need to see a reproducible example first. I suggest you post a new question with (only) this problem.

Comment: I want to clear someplace...why here add `select="text()[3]"` as the solution?

Comment: Because you want to sort by the 3rd text node of `tp` (which is the result of `(td[3] - td[4]) div td[4] * 100`). The idea here is to perform the calculation only once. In XSLT 1.0 you would have to do it twice - once for sorting and once for the output.